# Additional serial ports are half working: why is that?

Tags: linux, debian, embedded-linux, debian-buster

I have an embedded board with 2 serial ports and an additional PCI dual serial port + LPT, to reach a total of 4 serial ttys, though the added ttyS2 and ttyS3 *almost* don't work.
The system runs Debian buster, with a very few packages added to minimal setup.
All the ports are recognized by kernel

```
[  +0,021002] 00:03: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
[  +0,021110] 00:04: ttyS1 at I/O 0x2f8 (irq = 3, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
[  +0,036520] 0000:04:00.0: ttyS2 at I/O 0xc030 (irq = 19, base_baud = 115200) is a ST16650V2
[  +0,035081] 0000:04:00.1: ttyS3 at I/O 0xc020 (irq = 16, base_baud = 115200) is a ST16650V2
```

and a successive test with setserial gives the same result.

Note however that a `dpkg-reconfigure setserial` does **not** write the file in */etc/setserial.conf* and I have no idea on why - I tried resolving copying configuration by hand.

From some applications like `minicom` I see ***no result*** in opening the port and connecting from a remote terminal, nothing sent, nothing received.
From a test application using `librxtx-java` it looks to be *sending* data, but when data is received what happens is

```
[mar23 08:42] irq 16: nobody cared (try booting with the "irqpoll" option)
[  +0,000014] CPU: 1 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/1 Not tainted 4.19.0-14-amd64 #1 Debian 4.19.171-2
[  +0,000003] Hardware name:  /, BIOS 5.6.5 12/18/2018
[  +0,000002] Call Trace:
[  +0,000006]  <IRQ>
[  +0,000012]  dump_stack+0x66/0x81
[  +0,000008]  __report_bad_irq+0x3a/0xb4
[  +0,000006]  note_interrupt.cold.9+0xa/0x63
[  +0,000008]  handle_irq_event_percpu+0x6d/0x80
[  +0,000006]  handle_irq_event+0x3c/0x60
[  +0,000004]  handle_fasteoi_irq+0xa3/0x160
[  +0,000007]  handle_irq+0x1f/0x30
[  +0,000006]  do_IRQ+0x49/0xe0
[  +0,000005]  common_interrupt+0xf/0xf
[  +0,000003]  </IRQ>
[  +0,000007] RIP: 0010:cpuidle_enter_state+0xb9/0x320
[  +0,000006] Code: e8 7c 85 b2 ff 80 7c 24 0b 00 74 17 9c 58 0f 1f 44 00 00 f6 c4 02 0f 85 3b 02 00 00 
[  +0,000003] RSP: 0018:ffffb9e30020be90 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: ffffffffffffffd7
[  +0,000005] RAX: ffff9329f8122140 RBX: 000000ae53921a15 RCX: 000000000000001f
[  +0,000002] RDX: 000000ae53921a15 RSI: 0000000060062542 RDI: 0000000000000000
[  +0,000003] RBP: ffff9329f812a248 R08: 0000000000000002 R09: 0000000000021a00
[  +0,000002] R10: 000000ecc794a002 R11: ffff9329f8121128 R12: 0000000000000001
[  +0,000002] R13: ffffffffa98b70b8 R14: 0000000000000001 R15: 0000000000000000
[  +0,000011]  do_idle+0x228/0x270
[  +0,000006]  cpu_startup_entry+0x6f/0x80
[  +0,000005]  start_secondary+0x1a4/0x200
[  +0,000006]  secondary_startup_64+0xa4/0xb0
[  +0,000005] handlers:
[  +0,000009] [<00000000920e25ee>] serial8250_interrupt
[  +0,000005] Disabling IRQ #16
```

I read a few articles and did a quick read of Serial-HOWTO, but it seems that once `setserial` has found the correct configuration everything should go as intended, so I have no clue on what's going on

---- EDIT

Well, I (almost) resolved: the board has 2 serial and 1 parallel, all connected to an external device. I ***mismatched*** a non-standard external connector and routed some RS232 level signals into the parallel port: that resulted to be **fatal**.
The confusing result is that the controller looked to still be working, while it isn't 100% doing so.
I'm waiting to get a new board...

Comment: Care to provide the name of the card you are talking about? Best is to add output of `lspci -vv -nk -s 4:0` and `cat /proc/interrupts`. Also provide a kernel version and meanwhile try the latest one (v5.11.* as of today) if it has the same issue.

Comment: Have you tried a loopback test on each port? Are you sure hardware flow control is disabled?

Comment: Thanks for commenting, I found the problem and it was none of software. The board has also a parallel port, all connected to an external device: a wrong connection routed some external RS232 lines to the parallel, **frying** the controller - my fault!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I (almost) resolved: it's all about an hardware fault.

The board has 2 serial and 1 parallel, all connected to an external device. I ***mismatched*** a non-standard external connector and routed some RS232 level signals into the parallel port: that resulted to be *fatal*.

The confusing result is that the controller looked to still be working, while it isn't 100% doing so. I'm waiting to get a new board...

Comment: The new board still generates the **Disabling IRQ #16** message, from time to time. What I suspect now is that IRQ 16 is conflicting with the PCI bridge interrupt... Any idea on how to change it?